# How do you (not) apply the mean value theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x) = (x^2 , x^3)$.

How to show there exist no $ξ \in [0,1]$ such that $f (1) − f (0) = Df (ξ) (1−0)$?

My solution:

$f(1)=(1 ,1),\ f(0)=(0 , 0) \implies f(1)-f(0)=(1 , 1)$

$Df(x)=( 2x , 3x^2)$, so $Df(ξ)= (2xξ,3x^2ξ)(1−0)=(2xξ,3x^2ξ)$ but that isn`t equal to $(1 ,1)$ for any $ξ \in [0,1]$.

Did I take the wrong approach?

Comment: Please use mathjax https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Note $Df(\xi) = (2\xi, 3\xi^2)$ and so $Df(\xi)(1-0) = (2\xi,3\xi^2)$, not as you have written.